# Comma before "because" in this sentence?

Tags: commas

According to http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/when-to-use-a-comma-before-because , the comma can easily change the meaning of a sentence that contains "because." A perfect example is, "He didn't run away, because he was afraid," versus, "He didn't run away because he was afraid." I am usually very good at figuring out how to use a comma before "because" so that there is no confusion.

Which sentence is correct? I am trying to explain why someone said specific comments.

**1. "The comments about the power outage were said, because there was a power outage last year."**

**2. "The comments about the power outage were said because there was a power outage last year."**

Comment: I would use "made" instead of "said." Also, using the passive voice makes this sentence more vague than it may need to be (or perhaps not, if using a passive construction was your intention). Consider saying it this way (if you agree): "He commented on the power outage because there had been one last year." Or, "The comments about the power outage were made because there had been a power outage last year." In either case I don't think a comma before "because" is required, because there is no pause in the statement when said out loud (as there is in this sentence I've just written).

Comment: The source you quote states: "You don’t *automatically* put a comma before the word because, but *sometimes you need a comma there* to make sure your meaning is clear." *[emphasis added]*. I read that as meaning that *usually* you do ***not*** need a comma - unless there is ambiguity. Personally, I can't see any ambiguity in your sentence; hence the quoted rule suggests a comma is **not** required (as already suggested by @MarkHubbard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the prior commentator noted, you need to change "said" to "made" to make the sentence idiomatically correct.

In your examples, the clause that begins with *because* is an adverbial clause, which is defined as a clause that functions to modify the main clause by answering such questions as why, when, where, how, under what condition. Adverb clauses begin with subordinating conjunctions--in your example, *because*.  An adverb clause at the beginning of the sentence is usually set off by a comma, but such a clause in the second position is not set off by a comma.

As the first comment noted, it is better to shift from the passive to the active voice--that is, put an actor in the first position: **A speaker made comments about the power outage because an outage occurred last year.**  Active voice is the natural voice in English, and this construction would be both grammatically and idiomatically correct.